# SslStream, как отключить кэширование сеанса?

Tags: c#

В документации сказано:

> Платформа Framework кэширует сеансы SSL при их создании и пытается повторно использовать кэшированный сеанс для нового запроса, если это возможно. При попытке повторного использования сеанса SSL платформа Framework использует первый элемент ClientCertificates (если таковой существует) или пытается повторно использовать анонимные сеансы при пустом значении ClientCertificates.

Как отключить кэширование?

В данный момент есть проблемы с повторным подключением к серверу (т.е. при первом подключении все проходит удачно, при повторном - сервер рвет сессию. Если перезапустить приложение - опять первое подключение удачно, повторное - разрыв сессии), думаю проблема либо в кэшировании, либо SslStream досих пор не пофиксили и клиент не закрывает корректно сессию: [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237807/net-sslstream-doesnt-close-tls-connection-properly)

**Update**

Дело 100% в кэшировании сессии!

Дошли руки, проверил сниффером пакеты. Различаются сообщения типа Client Hello в одном месте.

Первое подключение к серверу (успешное): [скриншот](http://i6.5cm.ru/i/qgk1.png)

Второе подключение к серверу без перезапуска программы (не успешное): [скриншот](http://i6.5cm.ru/i/kxjq.png)

Думаю различие в идентификаторе сессии видно невооруженным взглядом.

p.s. очень не хочется использовать сторонние ssl клиенты. Есть ли разумный выход из ситуации?

Comment: А вы не пробовали workaround, описанный в ответе по вашей ссылке? Просто для эксперимента.

Comment: VladD, сейчас попробую, но сами понимаете - это костыль.

Comment: Костыль, конечно. Но по крайней мере, этот костыль [одобрен Microsoft](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/788752/sslstream-does-not-properly-send-the-close-notify-alert): "_In the meantime, please consider using Windows.Networking.Sockets API or the workaround mentioned in the Wokarounds section._" (А в Wokarounds section ссылка на ответ на SO).

Comment: В моем случае данное решение не помогло. Буду дальше разбираться с кодом. Спасибо.

Comment: Жаль, конечно. Я, к сожалению, не сетевик, вряд ли смогу помочь.

Comment: VladD, обновил ответ. Думаю по скриншотам ясно в чем дело. Если не сложно, прошу вас задать этот вопрос на stackoverflow.com на английском языке, для меня это языковой барьер, и скорее всего просто заминусуют из-за некорректного правописания.

Comment: Просто еще дело в том, что дубли вопроса висят на кибере и msdn, так никто и не ответил.

Comment: Попробую не забыть завтра. Сегодня уже поздновато...

Comment: Что за сервер-то? Кстати, приложите по-больше примеров трафика, а то по одному пакету ничего не ясно. Особенно интересует ответ сервера на попытку возобновления сеанса.

Comment: Pavel Mayorov, при повторном подключении без перезапуска программы SslClient присваивает уже не нулевой id сессии. Соответсвенно логика ответа сервера меняется. Мне бы только кэширование отключить, сердствами ОС, апи или управляемого кода. Т.е. чтобы при повторном подключении была опять нулевая сессия. А клиент менять не хочу потому что в программе уже используютя TcpClient и NetworkStream. Менять клиент - почти всегда значит переделывать логику под сокеты. В программе же используется как защищенные, так и не защищенные соединения.

Comment: @z668: Опубликовал: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30079379/276994

Comment: VladD, благодарю.

Comment: @z668: Не за что. Посмотрим, что скажет коллективный разум.

Comment: z668, вы не ответили на мой вопрос. Какой сервер используется и какие ответные пакеты он посылает?

Comment: Pavel Mayorov, сервер коммерческий, не хотелось бы раскрывать подобную информацию. Да от нее в данном случае ничего и не зависит. В любом случае хоть и костылями - но проблема решена.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

К сожалению, кеширование происходит во внутреннем классе, и честно говоря не нашел в коде каких-либо точек, позволяющих его отключить полностью. Как вариант - можете между подключениями чистить кеш через Reflection:

```
var sslAssembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(SslStream));

var sslSessionCacheClass = sslAssembly.GetType("System.Net.Security.SslSessionsCache");

var cachedCredsInfo = sslSessionCacheClass.GetField("s_CachedCreds", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
var cachedCreds = (Hashtable)cachedCredsInfo.GetValue(null);

cachedCreds.Clear();
```

Хотя конечно тоже костыль.. Вообще вся эта история с отключением кеширования сеансов является бооольшим костылем. Оно не должно никогда отключатся для клиента.

Самым правильным решением было бы исправление проблемы внутри серверной части. Попробуйте поговорить с разработчиками серверного приложения к которому вы подключаетесь.

**Обновлено:** В случае с многопоточностью, можно ещё больше "закостылится", создав заглушку для Hashtable, ничего в себя не сохраняющую:

```
public class DummyHashtable : Hashtable
{
    public override object this[object key]
    {
        get { return null; }
        set { return; }
    }

    public override void Add(object key, object value)
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

Ну и соответственно вместо GetValue()/Clear() просто подменить значение этого поля:

```
var dummyCache = new DummyHashtable();
cachedCredsInfo.SetValue(null, dummyCache);
```

В итоге, кеш не сработает никогда.

Comment: Sergey Rufanov, благодарю за ответ. Тут скорее дело в недоработке SslClient Microsoft, у тех же EldoS в их SecureBlackbox.NET (хотя она мне крайне не нравится, не держит нагрузку) этот момент проработан.

Comment: О, и снова здравствуйте :-) У меня дежа вю.

Comment: @z668, Это да. Порой кажется, что сетевую часть CLR писали закоренелые C-шники, жутко ненавидящие ООП и всех других программистов. ) Достаточно было везде использовать публичные интерфейсы вместо internal/sealed-реализаций - тогда тестировать было бы в сотни раз проще, и проблема бы ваша решилась всего одним простым классом-наследником )

Comment: @SergeyRufanov: Возможно, тут ещё играет роль необходимость корректной работы, как бы юзер не перекрыл перекрываемые методы. Вот статья Эрика по этому поводу: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2004/01/22/61803.aspx

Comment: @VladD, не, ну зачем многие критичные классы сделали sealed - это понятно. Меня больше смущает то, что везде в полях указываются именно конкретные реализации, а не интерфейсы. )  Все причины из той статьи в этом случае сводятся на нет. Полностью новый класс, реализующий некий интерфейс, никак не ломает поведение старых классов реализующих его же.

Comment: @SergeyRufanov: Вы бы перенесли обновление в ответ на английском SO.

Answer (score 4):

После дня поисков чудом набрел на статью с блога msdn: [ссылка](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/huizhu/ssl-tls-full-handshake-vs-abbreviated-handshake)

> Windows дает возможность отключить кэширование SSL с помощью ключа регистра:
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE]
> [System]
> [CurrentControlSet]
> [Control]
> [SecurityProviders]
> [SCHANNEL]
> ClientCacheTime
> ClientCacheTime это DWORD в миллисекундах. Если Вы установите ключ в значение 0 и перезагрузите устройство, то кэширование SSL сессий не будет использоваться.

Создал x32 DWORD параметр в реестре, перезагрузил машину. Тем самым отключил кэширование всех SSL\TLS запросов в Windows. Это лишь костыль. Приму любой, более адекватный способ решения, т.к. этот способ требует:

а) прав администратора

б) внесение записи в реестр

в) удаления записи из реестра после удаления программы

Comment: ... ну и вообще это глобальное решение для локальной проблемы.

Comment: VladD, да, вы правы. Сам понимаю, но просто не вижу другого выхода. Дергать "System.Net.Security.SslSessionsCache" через рефлексию именно в моем случае не подойдет. Приложение многопоточное. Это создаст дополнительную, серьезную нагрузку.

Comment: Это как раз не проблема :-) Вы можете выдернуть `HashTable cachedCreds` _один раз_ при создании `SslStream`, и чистить кэш без всякого reflection'а.

Comment: VladD, если не затруднит, можно пример? Рефлектором смотрел, там класс SslSessionsCache  с модификатором Internal, даже не знаю как без рефлексии получить доступ к его полю.

Comment: VladD, эмм, я не так вас понял. Извините, просто голова уже с трудом соображает. Проблема в том, что SslClient создается и уничтожается в каждом потоке.

Comment: Угу, понимаю. Но при создании можно ж дёргать рефлексией сразу и `cachedCreds`? По идее, не должно быть медленно. `cachedCredsInfo` можно вычислить один раз при старте программы, это ещё сильнее всё ускорит.

Comment: Ой, подождите. Так `cachedCreds` — это статическое поле? Дайте-ка проконсультируюсь с рефлектором...

Comment: Угу, статическое. И я почему-то не вижу, где они защищаются от многопоточного доступа...

Comment: VladD, Лучше всего тестами на днях проверю. Спасибо за помощь и советы.

Comment: Надо внимательно поизучать их код рефлектором (или ILSpy'ем), чтобы понять, в какой точке можно безопасно чистить глобальный кэш. Хирургия ещё та.

Comment: @z668, можно создать деградировавшего потомка Hashtable, который ничего не будет сохранять.  Если заменить то поле его экземпляром, то кеширование совсем перестанет работать.. Добавил этот вариант в свой ответ )